# Как правильно писать адрес?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Пожарный проезд угол *Ново-Астраханское шоссе* или *Ново-Астраханского шоссе*?

Answer (score 1):

**Пожарный проезд, угол** (чего?) **Ново-Астраханского шоссе**

Обратите внимание на запятую.

P.S. Думаю, вам знакома популярная песенка: "Как на Дерибасовской, угол Ришельевской..." (http://www.karaoke.ru/artists/narodnaja/text/kak-na-deribasovskoj/)